# Cannot set background image for tabbar

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I'm having trouble setting the background image on my tabbar. I've upgraded to iOS5 and Xcode 4.2, and the tabbar background image just stopped working.

The tabbar is only present on my RootViewController.

I managed to use the Interface Builder and applied a background colour which is not exactly what I wanted but will do for now. This only works for iOS5 for some reason. Ideally I would like to do it programmatically. I'm trying to get the following code working:

RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITabBar *mainTabBar;
    IBOutlet UITabBarItem *settingsBarItem;
    IBOutlet UITabBarItem *infoBarItem;
    IBOutlet UITabBarItem *aboutBarItem;

}

@property (retain,nonatomic) UITabBar *mainTabBar;

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"]]; 
        if ([mainTabBar respondsToSelect:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)]){
            mainTabBar.backgroundImage = imageView;
        }
        else{
            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
            UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"];
            UIColor *c = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:i];
            v.backgroundColor = c;
            [c release];
            [mainTabBar insertSubview:v atIndex:0]; 
            [v release];
        }
}
```

This code is just not working for me, I must be doing something wrong, so any help appreciated.

I'm getting a couple of warning messages aswell:

1) Instance method '-respondToSelect:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

2) Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImage *' from 'UIImageView *'

EDIT

The entire code is too large to paste here, the RootViewController.h is http://pastie.org/3249124 and the RootViewController.m is http://pastie.org/3249137

Comment: Looks like a similar issue to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800474/custom-uitabbar-background-image-not-working-in-ios-5

Comment: I can help you with the 2nd warning, you should assign an image to this line `mainTabBar.backgroundImage = imageView;` , maybe try `mainTabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"];`

Comment: All, please see the following post for a work around.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909379/setting-a-background-image-for-a-tabbar

Comment: Please see the following link to the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909379/setting-a-background-image-for-a-tabbar

Answer (score 2):

this line, shouldn't it be

```
if ([mainTabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)])
```

`respondsToSelector:` not `respondsToSelect:`

also, just as it said exactly,

```
mainTabBar.backgroundImage = imageView;
```

should be

```
mainTabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"];
```

because `backgroundImage` is `UIImage` while your `imageView` is `UIImageView`

Edit

also, I find that the code in your else statement is kind of weird, try if this is working.

```
else
{
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"];
    UIImageView* imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:i];
    [mainTabBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0]; 
    [imageView release];
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
    if ([mainTabBar respondsToSelect:@selector(setTintColor:)])
    {
        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"];
        UIColor* c = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:i];
        mainTabBar.tintColor = c;
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"];
        UIColor *c = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:i];
        v.backgroundColor = c;
        [c release];
        [mainTabBar insertSubview:v atIndex:0]; 
        [v release];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks X Slash, that got rid of the warnings, but I'm still having the problem with the background image not appearing as expected.

Comment: oops, sorry, I just assumed your code (logic) is working but there are syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks X Slash, bit still no luck, that didn't work. I've edited my original post to link to full code listing.

Comment: sorry, I hope this last bit is working for you, if not, I don't have anything to offer you anymore

Comment: hi i want to set image to tabBar icon...image is colored image... how can i do this, if the image is black and white then i don't have any problem but its creating problem with colored image

Answer (score 1):

you have minor problem you pass imageview in  mainTabBar.backgroundImage it's worng , you will pass UIImage ... please check this code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
            if ([mainTabBar respondsToSelect:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)]){
                mainTabBar.backgroundImage =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"] ;
            }
            else{
                CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);
                UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
                UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smallMenuBackground.png"];
                UIColor *c = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:i];
                v.backgroundColor = c;
                [c release];
                [mainTabBar insertSubview:v atIndex:0]; 
                [v release];
            }
    }
```

Comment: I've edited the original post with links to the full code listing.

Comment: [mainTabBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0]; this code is replace by [mainTabBar  insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];