# UINavigationBar appearance override in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5

I have had the following code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarBackBlack.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarBackBlack.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.72 alpha:1.0]];
```

But now I want to have one place in my app where I want the navbar to be a different color than this universal color I've set throughout the app. How can I change this for this particular settings only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call setBackgroundImage on the instance of the navigation bar as well.

See this related post:

[Custom UITabBar background image not working in iOS 5 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800474/custom-uitabbar-background-image-not-working-in-ios-5/7801253#7801253)

You should also condition it on whether it responds to that selector:

```
if ([navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)])
{
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_brn.jpg"]];
}
else
{
    // ios 4 code here
}
```

Comment: how about the tint color? I can't seem to do that

Answer (score 0):

Just use the appearance methods directly on the navigation bar instance instead on the `appearance` proxy object.

```
[navBarInstance setBackgroundImage: ... ];
```