# PhoneGap TabBar custom font, background patterns

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying to costumize tabbar interface for my app, is it possibile to change font, font size, put custom backround pattern image?

I realy need to change it so it can fit my app needs.

Comment: yes you can easily do it with css3 , wich library do you use for tabbar? sencha touch or jquery mobile ?

Comment: i'm using Phonegap plugin, TabBar. I can manipulate it with css?

Comment: so you are using native tabbar ?! it's kind of bad idea but if you want to style it you should do it naively im suggesting you to use html-java script tabbar.

Comment: Ok, i was hoping i could easily style the native tabbar. Thanks anyway man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of the tab bar plugin ([repo on GitHub](https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-plugins)). It does not yet support changing the background image or the font, but it shouldn't be a big problem to implement this. I'll put it on the wishlist but at the moment I don't have time. If you want to implement it yourself in the meantime, look at the [tab bar's setBackgroundImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7801253/245706) method and in the plugin code, search for `selectedImageTintColorRgba` to see where you have to implement additional options.

Comment: Ok, thanks man! I'm short with time too, so i think this time im gonna go for html,css3 menu. Anyway realy nice work! Soon i get time, i'll start playing with the code.